# iOS NSDictionary Memory Pressure Crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have a very large model NSDictionary in which I store 400 companies information, then create NSArrays during initial load to be used in App for speed.  When I have about 100 companies it just ran slow, not it causes my App to crash due to memory pressure.  Any suggestions on how to architect this in a more efficient manner?

```
 - (NSArray*)exhibitorDetail{
NSDictionary *company1 = @{@"id": @"id1", @"name": @"company xyz", @"details": @"Booth: 1700", @"png": @"exhibitor_map1700.png"};
NSDictionary *company2 = @{@"id": @"id2", @"name": @"company abc", @"details": @"Booth: 1721", @"png": @"exhibitor_map1721.png"};
NSDictionary *company3 = @{@"id": @"id3", @"name": @"company mno", @"details": @"Booth: 805", @"png": @"exhibitor_map805.png"};
NSDictionary *company4 = @{@"id": @"id4", @"name": @"company efg", @"details": @"Booth: 1320, 1321", @"png": @"exhibitor_map1320.png"};
...through 400 dictionaries of companies.

 NSMutableArray *allCompanies = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:company1, company2, company3, company4,..]l

NSSortDescriptor *nameDescripter = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending: YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];

NSArray *descriptors = @[nameDescripter];

[allCompanies sortUsingDescriptors:descriptors];

return allCompanies;
}
```

Then Dictionary for to be used for UITableView

```
- (NSDictionary*) countPerLetter {

NSDictionary *dictionary;
NSMutableArray *objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSArray *letters = self.exhibitorFirstLetter;
NSArray *names = self.exhibitorName;

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [self.exhibitorFirstLetter count]; i++)
{
    [objects addObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]];
}

dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects: objects forKeys:letters];

for (NSString *name in names) {   //zen software, zeb, bakken
    NSString *firstLetter = [name substringToIndex:1];  //z, b

    for (NSString *letter in letters) {  //z, b
        if ([firstLetter isEqualToString:letter]) {
            NSMutableArray *currentObjects = [dictionary objectForKey:letter];
            [currentObjects addObject:name];
        }
    }

}

return dictionary;
}
```

Here is my initial setup array, which essentially extracts Company "name" and Company "details" into single array for ease of use.  Running this calls the methods above and thus the crash.

```
 -(void) setupViewArrays {
ExhibitorData *ed = [[ExhibitorData alloc]init];
NSArray *exhibitorKeys = [ed.countPerLetter allKeys];
NSDictionary *exhibitorDictionary = [ed countPerLetter];

NSArray *exhibitorSetupArrays = @[exhibitorKeys, exhibitorDictionary];
}
```

Comment: Did you really type out 400 NSDictionaries?

Comment: Unfortunately yes.  There wasn't an easy way to load, so the details had to be typed in.  Should I have not used NSDictionaries?

Comment: you are getting the memory pressure, because you are adding images to dictionary. you should add the image paths rather images directly.

Comment: I think CoreData would be quite useful in this situation.

Comment: @pawan - I am essentially adding the path correct?  The images are already in my project.

Comment: @user3406093 you should consider database, rather then array. core data is a good choice.

Comment: Instead of putting these company details in code, you should put it in plain text of some sort (json or plist).  Then, as others have said, serialize this file into a database (Core Data).  I'm assuming you want to then put this content in a table view, which you can use NSFetchedResultsController as the data source for your table.